# Proper code to delete/or deactivate one constraint to add another to UIView

Tags: ios, swift

Why am I getting a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`?

I am trying to learn how to delete and create new constraints to `UIViews`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var red: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var green: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var redTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var greenToRed: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func shift(sender: AnyObject) {
    green.removeConstraint(greenToRed)
    let newGreen = NSLayoutConstraint(item: green, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    green.addConstraint(newGreen)
    newGreen.active = true
    red.removeConstraint(redTop)
    let newRed = NSLayoutConstraint(item: red, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: green, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    red.addConstraint(newRed)
    newRed.active = true}   }
```

[image: constraints]

Comment: Can you post the debugger output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints on a subview need to be added to the superview of the view involved. So a constraint between green and view needs to be added to view (since it's the superview of green). Similarly, a constraint between red and green also needs to be added to their common superview, view (the controllers self.view).

From Apple's documentation: "To make a constraint active, you must add it to a view. The view that holds the constraint must be an ancestor of the views the constraint involves, and should usually be the closest common ancestor. (This is in the existing NSView API sense of the word ancestor, where a view is an ancestor of itself.)".

Comment: OK! so I had to make `IBOutlet` view and call view.addConstraint and view.removeConstraint. TY you've been so much help to me

Comment: @Dustin, I thought "view" was the controller's self.view. If it is, you don't need to add an outlet for it.